# Video element not quite centered at all widths

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html5-video

So I have this video element that is centered for page widths over a certain number, but not always.  The element has been rotated and if the width of the page falls below the length of the element, things no longer center correctly. It's hard to explain but here's the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/05m04069/

You can shrink down the output window width-wise (make it skinnier) to see how things are no longer centered.

Posting the code here as well:

```
<body class="main-container">
<div class="centered" id="location-header">
  Seattle
</div>
<div id="clicktargetcontainer">
    <video loop muted  id="mainvideo" src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/123836285.hd.mp4?s=6ddd98cc75f1bb6fb776369a8fa372bf&profile_id=113" type="video/mp4" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline"e ad-outlet="video">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</div>
</body>
```

And here's the CSS as well:

```
video {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  transform:rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);

}

.main-container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I looked into this and I think there is a bug, or maybe just an inconvenient design decision in HTML/CSS.  If you take a landscape video, then rotate it 90deg (so that it is in portrait), the video element is still laid out as if the video was not rotated. I think there may be some way to change the positioning such that this is not a problem, but when I was trying to do that, it created many other issues with the other elements on the page. What I ended up doing was rotating all of my video content with video editing software and re-encoding it. I then no longer had to use the CSS rotation and the widths were correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the video in a container and do something like this

```
.video_contain {
position: absolute;
top: -50%;
left: -50%;
width: 200%;
height: 200%;
}

video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
min-height: 50%;
min-width: 50%;
}
```

the video will still stop scaling when it hits a min size though - that may be part of the issue you are having.